# Unable to save and read files on Flask application

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm setting up a flask application to run a machine learning model with a user interface.
I'm running python3 on sublime text (windows).
I'm unable to save files to the directory without it throwing up an error, PermissionDenied Errno13

My folder Web_Demo contains static, templates and main as is standard in Flask.

I've tried using the absolute path names but still had the same errors.

```
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]= 'D:/Web_Demo/static/'
@app.route('/analysis.html',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analysis():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            file=request.files["data"]
            filename=secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            return redirect(request.url)


    return render_template('/analysis.html')
```

I receive this error as soon as I press the button for upload. This is prior to me choosing and uploading the file itself.
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Web_Demo/static/'`

I believe I do not have the permissions to write to this folder. If so how do I accomplish this? I have read about solutions involving sudo 775 but could not implement or make sense of it.
Any help would be appreciated.

The entire traceback is as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\Web_Demo\main.py", line 34, in analysis
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
File "C:\Users\Utsav Dutta\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 2799, in save
dst = open(dst, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Web_Demo/static/'
```

Comment: sudo chmod -R 775 path/to/directory. Btw, if you are on windows, this command probably won't work. In that case start your shell/command prompt as admin.

Comment: I already tried running as administrator, but I face the same issue. I also checked permissions for this directory and write access is enabled for all users.

Comment: Would it be possible to read the file directly without saving it?

Comment: Can you provide the entire trace back of the error ?

Comment: I added the traceback onto the question itself. I am using Anaconda for python. Dont know if that could cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]= './static'` without the `/` at the end, normaly this should work.